# Is it a problem if multiple different accepting sockets use the same OpenSSL context?

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, boost-asio

Is it OK if the same OpenSSL context is used by several different accepting sockets?

In particular I'm using the same boost::asio::ssl::context with 2 different listening sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, SSL_CTX--which I believe is the underlying data structure--is just a global data structure used by your program. From ssl(3):

> **SSL_CTX (SSL Context)**
>
> That's the global context structure which is created by a server or client once per program life-time and which holds mainly default values for the SSL structures which are later created for the connections.

Comment: Do you mean yes it is ok because of that reason?

Comment: @Brian R. Bondy: I updated it to change the language...since I botched the 'Nope' part! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be OK.

For example a typical RFC4217 FTPS server will use the same SSL context for the control socket and all data sockets within that session.

Comment: Only within that session? Or within all sessions of the server?